# How do we access a file in github repo inside our azure databricks notebook

Tags: github, access-token, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-notebook

We have a requirement where we need to access a file hosted on our github private repo in our Azure Databricks notebook.
Currently we are doing it using curl command using the Personal Access Token of a user.

```
curl -H 'Authorization: token INSERTACCESSTOKENHERE' -H 'Accept: 
application/vnd.github.v3.raw' -O -L 
https://api.github.com/repos/*owner*/*repo*/contents/*path*
```

Is there a way we can avoid the use of PAT and use deploy keys or anything?

Comment: One option would be to use git (with ssh keys) to clone the whole repo and extract the file. But git doesn't support cloning only a single file so if the repo is large you'd have issues

Comment: @SamBob the file I want is a CSV file which is hosted on the github. And by default databricks workspace wont show csv files in the repo after clonning

Answer (score 3):

From summer 2021 databricks has introduced integration of git repos functionality.
More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos

If you add your file (excel, json etc.) in the repo, then you can use a relative path to access it and read it.

e.g. `pd.read_excel("./test_data.xlsx")`

Be aware that you need a cluster with a databricks version 8.4+ (or 9.1+?)

You can also test what is your current working directory by executing the following command.  `os.getcwd()`

If you have correctly integrated the repo then your result should be something like:

```
/Workspace/Repos/george@myemail.com/REPO_FOLDER/analysis
```

otherwise it will be something like: `/databricks/driver`

Comment: Really, it's available since 8.4

Comment: maybe, not sure about the exact version. I can update the answer

Comment: I was missing the `/Workspace/` in front of `/Repos/...`. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to specify a specific branch at runtime? Even if I have another branch checked out? Use case: run a scheduled task when there is active development of the project.

Comment: I dont think, however as a work around would be to use the databricks api, then create a repo with the branch you want in the databricks repo and then load the csv using that path.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate Git and azure databricks.

This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos#repos-can-contain-only-azure-databricks-notebooks-and-folders) shows how to integrate Git and azure databricks

**Step1:** Get raw URL of the File.

**Step2:** Use `wget` to access the file:

```
wget https://github.com/githubtraining/hellogitworld/blob/master/resources/labels.properties
```

Comment: The repo is a private repo and the file I want to read is a csv file.